# pandas - after combining data from two csvs, it only shows one cell per column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, if-statement

*please remember I am new to python and stack overflow!*

I have a csv I need to make in order to upload some data to another platform, it needs to be in this format and all the data is on a dataframe called 'results.' After changing some data based on conditions being true, I do not get anything in the 'Collection' column and only one cell in the handle and titles columns, where there is lot's of varying data. There are no errors, but, it does not give the desired output.[shopify_adapter.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pB3xb.png)

```
shopify_adapter = pd.DataFrame({
                    'Handle': [''],
                    'Title': [''],
                    'Collection': [''],
                    'Body (HTML)': [''],
                    'Vendor': [''], 
                    'Product Category': [''],
                    'Type': [''],
                    'Tags': [''],
                    'Published': [''],
                    'Option1 Name': [''],
                    'Option1 Value': [''],
                    'Option2 Name': [''], 
                    'Option2 Value': [''],
                    'Option3 Name': [''],
                    'Option3 Value': [''],
                    'Variant SKU': [''],
                    'Variant Grams': [''],
                    'Variant Inventory Tracker': [''],
                    'Variant Inventory Qty': [''],
                    'Variant Inventor Policy': [''],
                    'Variant Fulfillment Service': [''],
                    'Variant Price': [''],
                    'Variant Compare At Price': [''],
                    'Variant Requires Shipping': [''],
                    'Variant Taxable': [''],
                    'Variant Barcode': [''],
                    'Image Src': [''],
                    'Image Position': [''],
                    'Image Alt Text': [''],
                    'Gift Card': [''],
                    'SEO Title': [''],
                    'SEO Description': [''],
                    'Google Shopping / Google Product Category': [''],
                    'Google Shopping / Gender': [''],
                    'Google Shopping / Age Group': [''],
                    'Google Shopping / MPN': [''],
                    'Google Shopping / AdWords Grouping': [''],
                    'Google Shopping / AdWords Labels': [''],
                    'Google Shopping / Condition': [''],
                      'Google Shopping / Custom Product': [''],
                    'Google Shopping / Custom Label 0': [''],
                    'Google Shopping / Custom Label 1': [''],
                    'Google Shopping / Custom Label 2': [''],
                    'Google Shopping / Custom Label 3': [''],
                    'Google Shopping / Custom Label 4': [''],
                    'Variant Image': [''],
                    'Variant Weight Unit': [''],
                    'Variant Tax Code': [''],
                    'Cost per item': [''],
                      'Price / International': [''],
                    'Compare At Price / International': [''],
                    'Status': ['']
})
shopify_adapter["Handle"] = result['Artist'].astype(str) +" - "+ result["Title"] 
shopify_adapter["Title"] = result['Artist'].astype(str) +"-"+ result["Title"] 
result.loc[result['Medium'] == 'Original Artwork', shopify_adapter['Collection']] = 'Original Artwork'
result.loc[result['Medium'] != 'Original Artwork', shopify_adapter['Collection']] = 'Prints'








shopify_adapter.to_csv('shopify_adapter.csv')
```

desired output:
(with varying names in the title and artist section)
[desired output from shopify_adapter.csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAC0C.png)

I have tried using different forms of if statements and have tried only modifyng the "result" file.

thanks for any help

Comment: You should probably not use `result.loc[result['Medium'] == 'Original Artwork', shopify_adapter['Collection']]` but rather `result.loc[result['Medium'] == 'Original Artwork', 'Collection']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html), the second argument should be the name of the column. Thus, you should replace the `Collection` part with the following:

```
result.loc[result['Medium'] == 'Original Artwork', 'Collection'] = 'Original Artwork'
result.loc[result['Medium'] != 'Original Artwork', 'Collection'] = 'Prints'
```

In your case you are using the values in the `pd.Series` `shopify_adapter['Collection']` as an index. A easier example, so you can visualize better is something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Medium': ['a', 'b'], 'Collection': ['', '']})

# returns all rows with Medium 'a'
df.loc[df['Medium'].eq('a')]

# returns only the column 'Collection' for all rows with Medium 'a'
df.loc[df['Medium'].eq('a'), 'Collection']

# returns the columns df['Collection'] for all rows with Medium 'a' 
df.loc[df['Medium'].eq('a'), df['Collection']]
```

Comment: I ended up using gspread, but I can see how this would work, thanks!